# Does Firebase use the keychain in iOS applications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, keychain

I have a function to check if my application has a password saved into keychain of the app when its is opened. 
My function is added in my first ViewController and is this:

```
- (NSString *)tapGetButton{
    NSDictionary *info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *version = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSDictionary *query = @{
                        (__bridge id)kSecClass      : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: version,
                        (__bridge id)kSecReturnData : (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                        (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit : (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne
                        };

   CFDataRef token = nil;
   // 検索
   OSStatus err = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query,
                                   (CFTypeRef *)&token);

   NSString *accessToken = nil;

   // success
   if (err == errSecSuccess) {
       NSLog(@"Success: get token");
   }
   // not found
   else if (err == errSecItemNotFound) {
       NSLog(@"NotFound: get token");
   }
   else {
       NSLog(@"Error: get token");
   }

   return accessToken;
}
```

This funcitons works fine, I tested this and return correctly the password and username that I saved. But my problem appear when start the application then get this, and I find the problem. When I start the application, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the delegate is executed the init code to configure Firebase:

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

If I delete this code, the values from keychain is returned correctly, but if I add this code, the value returned is the number 1 or in other cases a long number...

Is Firebase using the keychain? There is other form of initialize Firebase?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not using Firebase to store the accounts or password, I'm using firebase to share events...

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase iOS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) uses keychain a lot. You could inspect source code. For example [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/InstanceID/FIRInstanceIDKeychain.m)

I would recommend you to define your own `service` and `account` values to identify your data more precisely:

```Swift
    let query: [String: Any] = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrAccount as String: "for example, token name",
        kSecAttrService as String: "for example, token provider name",
    ]
```